# DrawerNavigator - Route 'Page3' should declare a screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a DrawerNavigator router with 3 routes.
It didn't have any error when I only put Page1 and Page2 on the routes,
but when I add Page3 route, It has an error " **Route 'Page3' should declare a screen**. ". I believe that Page2 and Page3 have the same code structure and only different in rendering a View. Can someone tell me what happen?
Here's the full code.

```
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import SideBar from './SideBar';
import Page 1 from './Page1';
import Page 2 from './Page2';
import Page 3 from './Page3';

const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Page1: { screen: Page1 },
    Page2: { screen: Page2 },
    Page3: { screen: Page3 },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
  }
);

export default DrawerNav;
```

Comment: try to export that Page3 screen component. it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Actually I'm importing this const DrawerNav from StackNavigator component, and when I put this DrawerNavigator in the same file as StackNavigator, It doesn't have any error anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is bugs and fix it by these steps:

first call DrawerNav just once and summery your code to `export default DrawerNav  = DrawerNavigator .....` and delete last line! this is the result:

```
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import SideBar from './SideBar';
import Page 1 from './Page1';
import Page 2 from './Page2';
import Page 3 from './Page3';

export default DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Page1: { screen: Page1 },
    Page2: { screen: Page2 },
    Page3: { screen: Page3 },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
  }
);
```

then delete cache manually and update the project with `npm i` and then test that I hope your problem is solved when U see :)